# How to find the convergence of this serie?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm stuck with the convergence of this serie,
$$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty  \frac {2^{\ln(n)}}{2^n} $$ 
I tried ratio test and comparison test ...

Comment: MathJax hint:  to get multi character exponents, put them in braces like you did $n=1$ and the fractions.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\log\left(x\right)<x/2,\,x>0$ we have $$S=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{2^{\log\left(n\right)}}{2^{n}}\leq \sum_{n\geq1}2^{n/2-n}=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{2^{n/2}}=1+\sqrt{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the root test
$$
\left(\frac{2^{\log n}}{2^n}\right)^{1/n}
=\frac{1}{2}2^{\log n/n}\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}<1.
$$
as $n\to\infty$ since $\log n/n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ and $2^x$ is a continuous function. Hence the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $2^{\ln(n)}=2^{\log_2(n) \cdot \ln 2}=n^{\log 2} \lt n$ so you can compare with $\sum \frac n{2^n}$